# How to forward a photo from Telegram group chat to Slack (using Webhooks and Telegram Bot)?

Tags: python, json, telegram, webhooks, slack

I'm trying to build a Telegram bot which forwards messages from a Telegram group chat to a Slack channel using Webhooks.
at the moment, I was able to forward all text messages and photo captions (caption only).

If a file (photo, video, etc.) is sent in the connected group, is there a way to get it's URL and forward it to the post request to Slack?
When asked, Slack support told me I can send a URL but I couldn't find it the the JSON update sent by the Telegram bot when a file was sent.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching and asking experts,

after receiving `file_id` in the webhook update from the Telegram bot,
in order to get the image url as Slack requires, one should GET request the path from Telegram api using this URL:

```
"https://api.telegram.org/bot/<BOT_TOKEN>/getFile?file_id=<FILE_ID>"
```

and accessing 'file_path' under `json_dict['result']['file_path']`

The next step is to use the path and add it to this URL:

```
"https://api.telegram.org/file/bot/<BOT_TOKEN>/<FILE_PATH>"
```

then send a POST request to the slack webhook URL using the pattern mentioned in the link: https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks

more info can be found at TelegramAPI manual website:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile